# Calling C# method or function after Outlook email send button is pressed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have a small application that triggers an Outlook email to populate for a user to send based off another ASP gridview selection. My final piece of this is triggering a C# method in code behind. I want the method to be triggered once the user presses the send button on the newly opened email.

I have found some information on Application.Itemsend, but not enough to really tell me if this is the correct answer.

What do I need in order to capture the Send button event and trigger code behind?

Comment: if this Child window then you can monitor the button using jquery. Once the button is clicked do action

Comment: nikunjM, I'm not sure I understand you. Do you have an example you can show? I'm still asking the same question. How do you trigger something from the Outlook email send button press?

Comment: is your outlook open as child window? is this web application?

Comment: C# code behind prompts a child outlook message to open up. Yes, it is a web app

Comment: How are you getting the Outlook message to pop up? Are you using a link with `mailto:`?

Comment: I am using these two USING statements                                                   
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;  THEN

Comment: Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
 MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(outlookTemplate);            This opens it from a template I have saved.

Comment: You are aware that automating any Office product (including Outlook) from ASP.Net is completely unsupported, aren't you?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever. Clearly, I was not aware.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following code to get the send button event and bind the event to it. You can refer to the following code.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
        }

        private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
```

This code indicates that a "text" window pops up when the send button is clicked.